# How to plot the distribution of a graphs clustering coefficient

Tags: python, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, networkx

I'm new to networkx and pyplot and I was just wondering how I would go about plotting a distribution of a local clustering coefficient. Plotting a degree distribution was more straightforward since the degree_histogram function does it for you, but with this I'm not sure what to do.

```
g = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(1000, 0.02, seed = None, directed = False)
gc = g.subgraph(max(nx.connected_components(g)))
lcc = nx.clustering(gc)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could assign a color to each node depending on the clustering. Matplotlib's [`plt.get_cmap()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) can indicate a range of colors. And a [`norm`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html) tells how the clustering values will be mapped to that color range.  Optionally, a colorbar can be added to show the correspondence.

To simply show the distribution, a [histogram](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) can be drawn using the values of the clustering.

The example below uses slightly adapted parameters to create the graph.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import networkx as nx

g = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(50, 0.1, seed=None, directed=False)
gc = g.subgraph(max(nx.connected_components(g)))
lcc = nx.clustering(gc)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('autumn')
norm = plt.Normalize(0, max(lcc.values()))
node_colors = [cmap(norm(lcc[node])) for node in gc.nodes]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))
nx.draw_spring(gc, node_color=node_colors, with_labels=True, ax=ax1)
fig.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm), label='Clustering', shrink=0.95, ax=ax1)

ax2.hist(lcc.values(), bins=10)
ax2.set_xlabel('Clustering')
ax2.set_ylabel('Frequency')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]